# Release fails when deploying React app to Azure Web App with Azure DevOps

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I cannot get a Release pipeline in Azure DevOps to successfully deploy build files from a React app to an Azure App Service.
This is the YAML file for the app:

```
trigger:
- main

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build my web application'
  jobs:
  - job: 'Build'
    displayName: 'Build job'
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      demands:
      - npm

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '16.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build
      displayName: 'npm install and build'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: 'build'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
      displayName: 'Build artifact'
```

As you'd expect, this puts the resultant build files in 'drop'. I can confirm this by inspecting the contents of 'drop' as it is a Published Artifact I can click on in the Summary tab for the Build process.
It's the Release that fails. This is the log for the release:

```
2022-03-28T11:29:39.9940600Z ##[section]Starting: Azure Web App Deploy: my-app-serv
2022-03-28T11:29:39.9952321Z ==============================================================================
2022-03-28T11:29:39.9952723Z Task         : Azure Web App
2022-03-28T11:29:39.9953008Z Description  : Deploy an Azure Web App for Linux or Windows
2022-03-28T11:29:39.9953295Z Version      : 1.200.0
2022-03-28T11:29:39.9953540Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-03-28T11:29:39.9953833Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azurewebapptroubleshooting
2022-03-28T11:29:39.9954210Z ==============================================================================
2022-03-28T11:29:40.3697650Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'my-app-serv'
2022-03-28T11:29:42.3999385Z Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
2022-03-28T11:30:18.0663125Z Updating submodules.
2022-03-28T11:30:18.0670674Z Preparing deployment for commit id 'dc023bbe-d'.
2022-03-28T11:30:18.0672154Z Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
2022-03-28T11:30:18.0673178Z Running oryx build...
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1423345Z Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform nodejs --platform-version 16 -i /tmp/8da10ae4b1f9200 -p compress_node_modules=tar-gz --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log 
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1431972Z Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1453191Z You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1453685Z 
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1454256Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20211207.1, Commit: 46633df49cc8fbe9718772a3c894df221273b2af, ReleaseTagName: 20211207.1
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1457307Z 
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1463475Z Build Operation ID: |DTbD+7CrQyM=.49dfa157_
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1465355Z Repository Commit : dc023bbe-d46e-46f2-9d49-6e8157706c19
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1465695Z 
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1466122Z Detecting platforms...
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1466558Z Could not detect any platform in the source directory.
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1467416Z Error: Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'nodejs' in the repo.
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1469069Z Error: Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'nodejs' in the repo.\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform nodejs --platform-version 16 -i /tmp/8da10ae4b1f9200 -p compress_node_modules=tar-gz --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log 
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1469950Z Deployment Failed.
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1510175Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1525344Z ##[error]To debug further please check Kudu stack trace URL : https://$my-app-serv:***@my-app-serv.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
2022-03-28T11:30:19.1527823Z ##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
2022-03-28T11:30:30.1233247Z Successfully added release annotation to the Application Insight : my-app-serv
2022-03-28T11:30:32.2997996Z Successfully updated deployment History at (CUT)
2022-03-28T11:30:34.0322983Z App Service Application URL: http://my-app-serv.azurewebsites.net
2022-03-28T11:30:34.0390276Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure Web App Deploy: my-app-serv
```

The Release uses Azure Web App Deploy. App Type is 'Web App on Linux'. 'Package or Folder' is the 'drop' folder. Runtime stack is '16 LTS (NODE|16-lts)' (but it also doesn't work if that's empty).
The drop folder does not contain zipped output. I don't understand why the Release operation is referred to as a Zip Deploy. Am I missing something to avoid the error 'Error: Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'nodejs' in the repo.'?

I'm just expecting the contents in the 'drop' folder to be successfully copied to App Service, and the web app run so I can test it (and in the long time, setup automated tests).
I've tried a number of different things with the Build, including zipping the build artifacts, with no luck. I don't think the build is the problem though, as the files in the 'drop' folder are the files I want copied.
So I think it's the Release that's the problem. But that looks so simple.

I start with an Agent and add an Azure Web App deployment task. It seems to successfully pickup the drop folder, as I've tried other values that show an obvious error when that is wrong. The target App Service is Linux, so the Web App Deploy App type is set to 'Web App on Linux'.
I've seen a few different approaches in stackoverflow, but no answers to this approach. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, but on the surface it looks right, as if I get this right, I can easily manage manual deployments, authorisations, etc. as supported by Releases.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the issue has been solved. Please share more details so we can troubleshoot for you. Feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

- One of the possible workarounds that you can try is to make the `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT= FALSE`.
  After making this as false, you should be able to deploy the app.
- Also please refer these links with similar issue  for more information.
  [Reference 1](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/826) ,
  [Reference 2](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/755)

Comment: Hey @RickyB ! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?